# How to get error and stack trace as JSON in symfony2?

Tags: php, json, symfony

In dev mode I get a nice erorr message with stack trace if a controller has a serious problem. That's fine.

However, my current symfony2 application is a service used by an other application. It would be much more handy to get the same information as JSON or an other structured way withouth all the view centered html, css and java script.

I read [How to Customize Error Pages](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) but I don't understand how I can configure symfony to emit a JSON error message instead of HTML.

From the mentioned document I learned that there is already an `exception.json.twig` file which does this. How can I tell symfony to use this template instead of `exception.html.twig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I copied the file `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/views/Exception/exception.json.twig` 3 times to `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` and named the copies

- `error.html.twig`
- `exception_full.html.twig`
- `exception.html.twig`

I'm not to happy to copy framework code, but after all it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer because the Symfony documentation you linked to pretty much tells you everything you need to know.  Pay attention to this:

"If your listener calls setResponse() on the GetResponseForExceptionEvent, event propagation will be stopped and the response will be sent to the client."

So if you just create the JSON response and set it via `setResponse()`, you should be all set.

Comment: I don't understand where to put this things. What is _your listener_? Where do I create this _JSON response_? All I currently have is a failing controller. What do I have to add/create? Sorry, I don't understand where to start.

Comment: I quoted the Symfony link that you provided.  That link provides explanation and examples of what happens when exceptions are thrown.  For a more in-depth example look at Symfony's [How to Create an Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) which walks you through creating the listener that you want.